# How to stop javascript ajax requests in inactive Iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, polling

I have made Website, where various other pages are built-in as "apps" with i frames:

```
<iframe id="frame1" src="./app1.php">
<iframe id="frame2" src="./app2.php">
```

In these apps, there is javascript code executed, among others very high-frequent HTTP-Requests.

```
$('#app1button').click(function () {
     //Here i have to stop the HTTP-Requests which where fired from the JS of App2
     hideAllApps();
     showApp(app1);
});
```

app1 is polling information from a server very high frequently:

app1.php has Javascript in it::

```
 Handler = window.setInterval(getStatus, 100); //start status messages
```

When i now click on app2, the other app pops up, and i want to stop the javascript, which was loaded in app1.php, due to performance reasons.

```
$('#app2button').click(function () {
    //Here i have to stop the HTTP-Requests which where fired from the JS of App1
    hideAllApps();
    showApp(app2);
});
```

How can i do that? Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it that you want to close all concuring ajax calls or just stop sending them? Because a simple clearInterval would work for the later.

Comment: But with a simple "clearinterval" in my main page i can't address javascript that was loaded in an iframe - or am i wrong?

Comment: You are right, unless you affect it to "top" (your main window)... top.handler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From within frame2 you can try `window.parent.frame["frame1"].stop()` and in frame 1 you define stop() as a function which clears your interval.

Comment: Is there the possility to have a stop function which kills all Ajax-Request at once?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery

Comment: You have a timer running every 100ms that calls getStatus which I'm guessing sends an ajax request. Calling clearInterval will ensure that no NEW requests are sent, but you can't stop requests that have already been sent. FWIW, a roundtrip to your server will likely take ~100ms so your timer interval is too short in my opinion. I'd recommend lengthening the interval and call clearInterval when you want to stop sending requests.

Comment: @AidasBendoraitis - very cool. Wasn't aware of the abort function.

Comment: This looks nice. But I get the following error: window.parent.frame["frame1"] is undefined

Comment: Give your frames the name attribute like `name="frame1"`.

Comment: Hi, i can try it at the end of the week. Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 4):

Since all iframes have there own window.You can use `window.onfocus`. `window.onblur`. put code inside each iframe. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KzuLY/)

```
var Handler ;
window.onfocus = function(){
         Handler = window.setInterval(getStatus, 100); //start status messages

}
window.onblur = function(){

  clearInterval(Handler );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

make sure both iframes are are hidden on the page load

once you open them with

```
$('#app2button').click(function () {
```

add javascript code to load the content with

```
$('#app2button').html().load()
```